# What is `react/no-unused-state` and why is it bad?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Can someone explain exactly what `no-unused-state` means and why is it considered bad practice?

I can't seem to find any information other than the following sentence taken from the [commit](https://github.com/wbinnssmith/eslint-plugin-react/commit/1e5b989cf7299962e62e65574241b7288120dd61):

> This adds a new rule, react/no-unused-state, which discovers state fields in a React component and warns if any of them are never read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The eslint-plugin-react docs](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unused-state.md) give some examples for what's considered good and bad code.

If you keep state in your component which is not used, you include code in your application that fulfills no purpose.

That in turn brings a whole bunch of issues, including that you ship code which is effectively never tested, that you have to maintain code which brings no benefit etc.

Comment: Great answer - I would say that it's also a concern of code readability. Someone coming into that code in six months to fix an issue is going to have to spend time working out what this unused state is doing only to find out that it's "nothing"!